# Get the selected option id with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use jQuery to make an ajax request based on a selected option.

Is there a simple way to retrieve the selected **option id** (e.g. "id2") using jQuery?

```
<select id="my_select">
   <option value="o1" id="id1">Option1</option>
   <option value="o2" id="id2">Option2</option>
</select>


$("#my_select").change(function() {
    //do something with the id of the selected option
});
```

Answer (score 236, accepted):

You can get it using the [`:selected` selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/),  like this:

```
$("#my_select").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
});
```

Comment: How do I go about applying your solution in pure javascript?

Answer (score 29):

```
var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
```

then you do whatever you want with `selectedIndex`

I've reedited my answer ... since selectedIndex isn't a good variable to give example...

Comment: 2 comments here, he already has the DOM element with `this` inside an event handler, no need to perform a lookup again...and might want to pick another variable name, `selectedIndex` would be especially inaccurate here :)

Comment: yes ... sorry ... i was in a hurry ... and selectedIndex variable was in hand ...

of course he doesn't need to pass again .. i'll redo

Comment: Personally I choose this option bc it didn't require a .change function

Answer (score 25):

```
$('#my_select option:selected').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

Th easiest way to this is var id = $(this).val(); from inside an event like on change.

Comment: This returns the value of the selected option, not the ID (which is what the OP requested).

Comment: This only gets the value and not the id as asked in the question