# Jquery to get the id of selected value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list that fetches values from db as follows

```
$.get('/getJobs', function (jobs) {
        seljobs = jobs;
        var i = 0;
        jobs.forEach(function (n) {
                           alert("job id----"+n.id)// 32,67,45
                           alert("job names----"+n.names)//test1,test2,test3

            html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + n.names + '</option>';
            i++;
        });
        $('#jobSel').html(html);
    });
```

i have to get the `id` of selected dropdown value..

ic in my dropdown i have name values `test1,test2,test3` ans assosiated `id's 32,67,45,`

while selecting test1 i have to get id 32 and so ans so.How it is possible

```
<tr>
                        <td width="200px">Jobs</td>
                        <td> 
                            <select id="jobSel" class="longcombo"></select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Looks like that's covered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888446/get-the-selected-option-id-with-jquery

Comment: Are you trying to retrive the id or value for selected option. Since you are not setting id in html code. You are just alerting the id value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this

on change event

```
$("#jodSel").on('change',function(){
    var getValue=$(this).val();
    alert(getValue);
  });
```

Note: In `dropdownlist` if you want to set id,text relation from your database  then, set id as value in option tag, not by adding extra `id` attribute inside option its not standard paractise though i did both in my answer but i prefer example 1

**HTML Markup**

```
Example 1:
    <select id="example1">
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
        <option value="4">four</option>
    </select>
Example 2 :
    <select id="example2">
        <option id="1">one</option>
        <option id="2">two</option>
        <option id="3">three</option>
        <option id="4">four</option>
    </select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$("#example1").on('change', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});

$("#example2").on('change', function () {
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: he wants the id, not the value.

Comment: If am nt wrong op said he has item as test1, test2, test3 and have value as 32,33,34 so he wants to fetch those id assotiated with test1,test2 ....

Comment: Thnks for editing, was access frm my phone so cnt do proper formating.  Btw id of wut ?? Of dropdown or list item ??   .val() will give listitem selected value ie id whch  op has bind for respective item test1-32, test2-33 etc etc

Comment: For me the .val() was the good in a fully dynamically generated content. ( $("#formname select[name=myselect]").val(); ) Any other version (:select, find... ) just give me "undefined".  So thanks the idea of a simple ".val()" :)

Comment: @huncyrus: You might getting `undifined` coz there is no id in your option item , and yes even in my answer have written i prefer Example 1.

Answer (score 7):

Try the change event and selected selector

```
$('#jobSel').change(function(){
    var optId = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the id, then please update your code like

```
  html += '<option id = "' + n.id + "' value="' + i + '">' + n.names + '</option>';
```

To retrieve id,

```
$('option:selected').attr("id")
```

To retrieve Value

```
$('option:selected').val()
```

in Javascript

```
var e = document.getElementById("jobSel");
var job = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: OP looks for the id, not the value.

Answer (score 2):

First set a custom attribute into your option for example `nameid` (you can set non-standardized attribute of an HTML element, it's allowed):

```
'<option nameid= "' + n.id + "' value="' + i + '">' + n.names + '</option>'
```

then you can easily get attribute value using jquery `.attr()` :

```
$('option:selected').attr("nameid")
```

For Example:

```
<select id="jobSel" class="longcombo" onchange="GetNameId">
    <option nameid="32" value="1">test1</option>
    <option nameid="67" value="1">test2</option>
    <option nameid="45" value="1">test3</option>    
    </select>
```

Jquery:

```
function GetNameId(){
   alert($('#jobSel option:selected').attr("nameid"));
}
```