# get selected options ID using document.getElementID() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get selected Option id in javascript ,

```
personalData['childname']=window.frames[0].document.getElementById('student_name').value;
```

HTML::

```
<tr>
<td align="right" width="40%"><label for="student" class="student" data-icon="">Select Name</label></td>
<td><select class="field" id="student_name"  required="required"  >

</select></td>
</tr>
```

** Loading values dynamicaly **

This line gives me the value , how can i get the selected option's id ???

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888446/get-the-selected-option-id-with-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623110/get-an-elements-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not Tested*

```
var $select = $('#student_name', window.frames[0].document);
var id = $select.find('[value="' + $select.val() + '"]').attr('id');
```

or

```
var id = $('#student_name option:selected', window.frames[0].document).attr('id');
```

Comment: my bad, I was looking at his code and didn't see any jquery usage at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
personalData['childname']=window.frames[0].document.getElementById('student_name').getAttribute("id");
```

Comment: There's no reason to do `getAttribute('id')` here: you can just do `.id`.

Answer (score 0):

try

javascript:

`personalData['childname']=window.frames[0].document.getElementById('student_name').id;`

jQuery :

`personalData['childname']=$('#student_name option:selected',
window.frames[0].document).attr('id');`

Comment: Doing `getElementById('student_name').id` isn't any help; that just returns `student_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure `JS`:

```
var elem = window.frames[0].document.getElementById('student_name');
personalData['childname'] = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].id;
```

See [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2bmdn/)