# Pass Id from ajax to controller - Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to pass my id from ajax to my controller. I mostly see that it is being done through the url but is there any other way i could do this without using the URL?

**View**

```
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
<label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Item</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<select class="form-control" id="item" name="item" mulitple>
<option >
</option>
</select>

</select>
</div>
</div>


$('#item').change(function()
        {    
             id =$(this).val();
            alert(id);
        }

        )
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)

{
    $id = $request->id;
    $item = Item::all()->where('id',$id)->first();

}
```

Comment: Your input in the markup has an ID of Item and your script is targeting id=food. Also your label is targeting "select" which does not exist. And you have a select nesting within another select (that wont work)

Comment: @happymacarts  sorry i just edited that to what i have currently

Comment: I see no ajax request in this code. Do you intend to include it in the "Change" function?

Comment: Yes..because i am fetching the id of the items dynamically. I am able to output the id's respectively but the issue now is `passing it to the controller`

Comment: @happymacarts  well i only included a small part of the script. That is where i am fetching the id of the selected items

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery, you can use jquery's ajax method to send out variables or data to your controller on laravel. Just be sure to read on form method spoofing from the laravel docs in any case at all, [check it out here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing)

[Jquery's ajax documentation goes here.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Here's how it'd look like:

```
function usersManagementAjax(requestType, url, userData, modalSelector, modalFailedSelector){
modalSelector.modal('hide');
$.ajax({
    type: requestType,
    url: url,
    data: userData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        modalSuccess.modal('show');
    },
    error: function(data){
        if(data.responseJSON.errors.contactNumber){
            contactGrp.removeClass('has-success');
            contactGrp.addClass('has-error');
            contactGrpError.removeClass('hidden');
            contactError = true;
            contactErrorText.text(data.responseJSON.errors.contactNumber[0]);
            isValid();
        }

        if(data.responseJSON.errors.email){
            emailGrp.removeClass('has-success');
            emailGrp.addClass('has-error');
            emailGrpError.removeClass('hidden');
            emailError = true;
            emailErrorText.text(data.responseJSON.errors.email[0]);
            isValid();
        }
        modalFailedSelector.modal('show');
    }
}); }
```

And here's how a function in a controller would look like:

```
 public function update(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->id;
    $updateRules = [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'email',
            'max:120',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($userId)
        ],
        'college' => 'required|string|min:1|max:1',
        'contactNumber' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'min:11',
            'max:11',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($userId)
        ]
    ];

    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $updateRules);
    if($validation->fails()){
        return Response::json(
            array('errors' => $validation->getMessageBag()->toArray()), 404);
    }

    else{
        $user = User::find($userId);
        $user->name = $request->name;
        if(Auth::user()->role->role != "Admin"){
            $user->roleID = Role::$defaultRoleId;
        }

        else{
            $user->roleID = $request->role;
        }
        $user->collegeID = $request->college;
        $user->contactNumber = $request->contactNumber;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->save();

        return response()->json($user);
    }
}
```

**Be aware that this is just a code sample and I have only meant to give you an idea on how to work around this.** These are some code snippets from my current project.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that for ajax requests to work on a laravel project, you must include a X-CSRF-TOKEN for every ajax request. (Or you can simply remove the VerifyCsrfToken middleware) Link about this goes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

Comment: you can also add ```<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">``` to your layout.blade.php file Sometimes depending on your setup you may need to use this ```$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajaxSetup({
  headers : {
   'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
 });
})```

Comment: Yep. I'm currently using this method mentioned by happymacarts. Forgot to include it in my reply. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really know how your answer solves my question here

Comment: Which id are you referring to anyways? The html select's id?

Comment: Yes the html select id. i want to pass the id of any item which is selected to my controller

Comment: Or do you mean the currently selected option? If that's so, go check this out [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown) here.

Comment: The issue is not getting the id of the selected item but it is passing the id of the selected item  to the controller

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888447/6840113 then have an ajax request that would send this variable to your laravel controller.