# How to get the ID of the select-option element with "change" event listener?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, api

I am new into javascript, and I've been working on this "project", but I need some help because I'm stuck. I might've not expressed my self correctly in the title so here it is:

I would like to get the ID of an option element (`<select> <option id="#"> </select>`) by using the `"change"` event listener on the `<select>.` So when I choose for example `"Action"` from the select `dropdown`, I'd like that change to trigger a function that will get that element's ID and use it in a function down below. Here's the code that I have so far, which basically does the following:

1.) Gets the genre list;

2.) Then for every item in the `response.data.genres`, sets a number which corresponds to the length of the array (total 19 items).

3.) If the selected `"option"` element matches the name of the genre in the array, then it defines the genre ID(the integer) and makes another request to the API in order to list the movies matching that genres ID. Thanks in advance.

```
//Genres
function genres(){
    //API request.
    axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=<API_KEY>&language=en-US")
        .then((response)=>{
            //console.log(response);

            let genres = response.data.genres;
            genres.length;
            console.log(genres)
            for(var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++){
                var genresId = response.data.genres[i];
                var tag = document.getElementById("Thriller");
                console.log(genresId);
                if(tag.id === genresId.name){
                   let genre = genresId.id;
                   axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=<API_KEY>&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres="+genre)
                    .then((response)=>{
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your select-option code and the change event code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the selected option id with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888446/get-the-selected-option-id-with-jquery)

Comment: I don't see how could it be marked as a possible duplicate of that question when thats for jQuery only, and this is only for vanilla Javascript. Nonetheless, will find a solution somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

So there are two steps if I understand correctly.
1. get the list of genres and fill a selectbox with it.
2. get a list of movies if an option in the selectbox is selected.

The first step, you can do with an innerHTML method. For every genre that is returned, you build a string like `<option value='genre'>genre</option>`. With innerHTML you add these options to the select box. The value property is what you use to see which option is selected.

Next we add an eventlistener to the dropbox so our script will react to the changes the user makes. The event we're listening for is 'change' and it will trigger the function 'getMovies'. See [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) for more info. `event.target.value` will give you the value of the selected option, which you can use as genre id.

Inside this function you will do your second api call to get your movie list.

A simple example without the api calls is this:

```js
let genreDropdown = document.getElementById('genre');
genreDropdown.innerHTML = getGenres();
genreDropdown.addEventListener("change", getMovies);

function getGenres(){
    let genres = ['action', 'romcom', 'thriller']; //this would be replaced with the api call to get the genres
    let innerHtml = '';
    
    for(var i = 0; i < genres.length; i++){
      var option = '<option value='+genres[i]+'>'+genres[i]+'</option>';
      innerHtml += option;
    }
    return innerHtml;
}

function getMovies(event) {
   let genre =  event.target.value;
   alert(genre) //you can replace this with the api call to get the movies.
}
```

```html
<select id='genre'>
  <option>loading...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Code will look for a `<select>` (its id to be exact) Element and on change it will output the ID of the Direct Child (`<option>` in this case).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myDropdown").on("change", function(){
    the_id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id")
    $("#output").html(the_id);
  });
});
```

I have made an Example for you > [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnq57jrr/1/)

Hope you can use the jQuery Code.