# How do I change the selected option of a Form::select from another Form::select's change event without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, laravel

This is not my code. I'm tasked to make changes. I have here two Form::select and I want to change the selected option of one when the other one's selected option has changed. I made a change event and I am able to change the value of the other Form::select through the use of the `val()` function of jQuery but it requires me to reload the page. What I was hoping to do was that changing the selected option of one would automatically change the selected option of the other without reloading the page.

Should I change null which is the default selected option into a variable? However it would be a PHP variable and I'm unable to change it with jQuery. I'm currently using Laravel framework, can I put a jQuery variable into the `Form::select`?

`{!! Form::select('start_time_hour', $select_hours_minutes['hours'], null, ['id' => 'start_time_hour', 'class' => 'select2']); !!}`

`{!! Form::select('over_work_hour_'.$i, $select_hours_minutes_with_blank['hours'], $shift_deduct_break['over_work_hour'], ['id' => 'over_work_hour_'.$i, 'class' => 'shift_deduct_breaks select2']); !!}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888446/get-the-selected-option-id-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

hope can help you

```
$('.select1').on('change', function() {
    $('.select2').val($(this).val())
})
```

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjYPom)

Comment: I already did this and it doesn't change the selected option of the other Form::select right away. I have to reload the page to see the change.

Comment: @Lorenz why you must reload page? Can you put all your code here or to a online flatform to check

Comment: I look up into the comment to my question and I finally found the answer. I need .trigger('change'); together with val() in order for the change to be seen without reloading the page. Using val() alone doesn't seem to work without reloading the page.